# Tab button background moving to the active one

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    .tabcontainer{
        text-align: center;
    }

    .buttonHolder {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .buttonHolder button {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    .buttonHolder button:hover {
        background-color: #831697;
    }

    .buttonHolder button.active {
        background-color: #831697;
    }

    .tabcontent {
        display: none;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tabContainer">
        <div class="buttonHolder">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'gamingInventory')">Gaming Inventory</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'merchandise')">Merchandise</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="gamingInventory" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
      
    <div id="merchandise" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p> 
    </div>
<script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I created a tabbed pane on html for my project and I want to have an animation that looks like the background color is moving across the active tab button. I hope you can understand what I'm saying. I'm kinda new to html and css and I'm having trouble achieving my goal.

I'm using wordpress so I have a choice of using plugins but I want to learn more without using plugins. Thank you!

Comment: Please explain more what you want to achieve, do you want it should fade in?

Comment: I want the background color of the buttons to slide across active ones. like if the button1 is active and I clicked on button2, the background from the button1 slides to button2. I hope that makes sense lol

Comment: You can make a div and display it when the button is clicked and when other button is clicked you can resize the div using JavaScript. Just try to fiddle a little with it do let me know if this works I may try to provide an answer then.